# Automatically execute a python script that sits on a Digital Ocean droplet using crontab?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I have a very simple test python script as seen below. This script sits on my Digital Ocean droplet.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import datetime
import time

def main():
    f = open('output.txt','a')
    f.write("Hello World! @ :" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " --> _the_finish_\n")
    print("Hello World! @ :" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " --> _the_finish_\n")
    f.close

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(2):
            main()
            time.sleep(5)
```

I want this script to execute automatically using crontab. My crontab execution line is the following:

```
 48 15 * * * /usr/bin/python3 /root/test_script/systemtime.py >> /tmp/systemtime.log 2>&1
```

The trouble I'm having is finding where or how to locate the python3 path in my Digital Ocean droplet, 1) where can I find or locate this python path I'm supposed to use? I don't have a tmp file in my Digital Ocean droplet, 2) so where will the .log file be stored? How can I configure the path for where the output will be stored?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

1. A way to find the Python path is running `whereis python3`. First make sure that it is installed.
2. It won't be stored. You should change `/tmp/systemtime.log` to your desired path. For instance, `/root/test_script/test_script.log`.

Btw, if you are using python3 you may want to change your shebang to `#!/usr/bin/env python3`.